# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt$ if $g_n \nearrow g$ and $g^+ \in L^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $g_n: [0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be measurable for all $n\in \Bbb N$, and $g_n \nearrow g: [0,1]\to \Bbb R$. Let $g^+ = \max\{0,g\}$. Assume $g^+ \in L^1[0,1]$. Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt.$$

**My work.** My guess is that the limit approaches $\int_0^1 g(t)\, dt$. However, the correct limit (this is a quals problem) seems to be $\int_0^1 g^+(t)\, dt$. I have shown my work below.

As $g_n \nearrow g$, $g$ is measurable. $g^+$ is also measurable. We have
$$\left| \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt - \int_0^1 g(t)\, dt \right| \le \left|\frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt  - \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng(t)})\, dt  \right| + \left| \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng(t)})\, dt  -\int_0^1 g(t)\, dt \right|.$$

We can control the second term using Lebesgue's DCT. We have $$\frac{\ln (1+e^{ng(t)})}{n} \le \frac{\log 2}{n} + g(t) \le 1 + g^{+}(t) \in L^1[0,1]$$
implying $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng(t)})\, dt  -\int_0^1 g(t)\, dt \right| = 0$$
by DCT. As a result, for some $N_1 \in \Bbb N$, we have
$$\left| \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng(t)})\, dt  -\int_0^1 g(t)\, dt \right| < \frac \varepsilon 2$$ for all $n\ge N_1$.

The first term is $$\left|\frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt  - \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng(t)})\, dt \right| = \left| \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{ng_n(t)}}{1 + e^{ng(t)}}\right)\, dt\right|$$
As $g_n \nearrow g$, we get $$\ln \left(\frac{1+e^{ng_n(t)}}{1 + e^{ng(t)}} \right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$
So, for some $N_2 \in \Bbb N$, $$\left|\ln \left(\frac{1+e^{ng_n(t)}}{1 + e^{ng(t)}} \right)\right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ for all $n\ge N_2$. Hence, for $n\ge N:= \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, we have
$$\left| \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt - \int_0^1 g(t)\, dt \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2N} < \varepsilon.$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n \int_0^1\ln (1+e^{ng_n(t)})\, dt = \int_0^1 g(t)\, dt.$$

---

I'd like to know where I'm going wrong, and how to justify the correct limit $\int_0^1 g^+(t)\, dt$. I guess my estimate of the first term might be incorrect. Thanks!

Comment: The pointwise limit of $\frac1n \ln(1+e^{ng(x)})$ isn’t $g(x)$, it’s $g^+(x)$, since if $g(x)$ is negative, $e^{ng(x)}$ goes to zero.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the same conclusion holds on any finite measure space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments can be simplified a little. Notice that
\begin{align}
\frac1n\log(1+e^{ng_n})&\leq \frac1n\log2\,\mathbb{1}_{\{g_n<0\}} +\frac1n\log(2e^{ng_n})\mathbf{1}_{\{g_n\geq0\}}\\
&=\frac1n\log2 + g^+_n\leq \log2+g^+
\end{align}
on account that $g_n\nearrow g$. One can then apply dominated convergence  convergence to get
$$
\lim_n\frac1n\int_{[0,1]}\log(1+e^{ng_n})=\int_{[0,1]}g^+$$
for on $\{g\leq0\}$
$$\frac1n\log(1+e^{ng_n})\leq\frac{\log2}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
and on $\{g>0\}$, by L'Hospital rule for example
$$\frac1n\log(1+e^{ng_n})\stackrel{n}{\sim}\frac{e^{ng_n}g_n}{1+e^{ng_n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}g
$$

---

**Comment:** Observe that the same argument carries over to any finite measure space $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$.